# Двоеточие в определении конструктора

Tags: c++, конструктор

У меня возникла проблема с пониманием синтаксиса. Увидел вот такой конструктор:

```
foo(char *msg) : msg(msg) { ..... }
```

Что значит двоеточие после аргумента в первых скобках?

Answer (score 15):

Область кода за двоеточием и до начала тела конструктора называется *списком инициализации членов* (англ. "member initializer list").

Используется как для инициализации членов класса, так и для вызова конструктора базового/базовых классов, т.е. по сути, инициализации базовой составляющей. Также здесь может быть вызов другого конструктора текущего класса (делегирование конструкторов, начиная с c++11).

Без инициализатора конструктора не обойтись, если в классе присутствует член ссылочного типа или константа, или член класса, у которого нет конструктора по умолчанию:

```
struct S {
   S(int) {}  // Конструктор с параметром. Не является конструктором по умолчанию.
};

class B {
public:
   B(int i) : i(i), r(i), s(i) {
    // this->i = i; // Ошибка. Нельзя присваивать константе.
    // r = i;       // Ошибка. Не является инициализацией ссылки.
    // s = S(i);    // Ошибка. `s` должен быть создан в инициализаторе конструктора.
   }
private:
   const int i;
   int& r;
   S s; 
};
```

т.к. код, начинающийся за фигурной скобкой будет приводить уже не к инициализации члена, а к присваиванию ему значения, чего нельзя сделать для упомянутых ранее ссылок или констант.

Дополнительно стоит заметить (как было упомянуто в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468496/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/468507#comment520809_468497) [Monah Tuk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189892/monah-tuk)), что если член-класса не инициализирован явно в инициализаторе конструктора и при этом ему присваивается значение в теле конструктора, то он сначала будет инициализирован конструктором по умолчанию (или инициализацией в определении класса (c++11)):

```
class D {
    int i = 42; // Инициализация члена в определении класса
};
```

После чего выполнится присваивание в теле конструктора. Для сложных классов это может приводить к дополнительным расходам.

Т.о. инициализацию членов стоит производить либо в определении класса, либо в инициализаторе конструктора. Не стоит пытаться сделать нечто подобное непосредственно внутри тела конструктора.

Answer (score 6):

```
class foo
{
public:
   foo(int a) : a(a) {}
   // эквивалентно foo(int a) { this->a = a; }
private:
   int a;
}
```

Это вообще-то база синтаксиса определения конструкторов в плюсах.

Еще может быть:

```
class foo : public bar 
{
public:
   foo(int a) : bar(a) { ... }
}
```

В этом случае, после двоеточия вызывается конструктор базового класса. ЕМНИП (могу ошибаться), в случае базового класса это единственный верный способ его вызова, т.е. написать вот так:

```
foo(int a) { bar(a); ... }
```

будет неверно.

П.С. Думаю, ответ alexolut более полон, чем мой.

Comment: Не могли бы вы эквивалентную запись для второго случая сделать?

Answer (score -1):

Это использование списка инициализации (Initialization List) для конструктора. Эта запись эквивалентна строчке кода в начале конструктора

```
this->msg = msg;
```

Comment: Не эквиваленто для ссылок и констант. К тому же инициализация и присваивание это не одно и то же.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что эквивалент не 100%. Если присваивание вызывется в теле конструктора, то объект до этого конструируется конструктором по умолчанию, а потом используется вызов оператора присваивания. Если член инициализируется при объявлении (C++11 и новее), то, в случае присваивания в теле конструктора будет сначала эта инициализация вызвана, а потом уже оператор присваивания.

Comment: В случае инициализации в Initialization List инициализация при объявлении будет пропущена и будет вызвана только одна операция. Т.е. при использовании списка инициализации у вас гарантированно меньше накладных расходов. Хотя я не знаю как в этих местах работают оптимизиторы компиляторов, может что и могут заоптимиздить. Ну и чтиво: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list