# Перегруженные конструкторы?

Tags: c++, конструктор

В заголовочном файле:

```
#include "Client.h"

class EthernetClient : public Client {

public:
  EthernetClient();
  EthernetClient(uint8_t sock);
private:
  uint8_t _sock;
};
```

Реализация:

```
EthernetClient::EthernetClient() : _sock(MAX_SOCK_NUM) { }

EthernetClient::EthernetClient(uint8_t sock) : _sock(sock) { }
```

`MAX_SOCK_NUM` дефайн, определенный где-то ранее. Собственно не понятно, что значат эти строки:

```
EthernetClient::EthernetClient() : _sock(MAX_SOCK_NUM) { }

EthernetClient::EthernetClient(uint8_t sock) : _sock(sock) { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это перегруженные конструкторы. Первый конструктор без параметров, а второй принимает скорее всего кол-во сокетов. Но так как кол-во сокетов нужно самому классу, в первом случае он инициализирует заведомо заготовленной константой. В целом - обычный код.

Comment: _sock(MAX_SOCK_NUM)  такая запись инициализация, и по сути равна `EthernetClient::EthernetClient() {_sock = MAX_SOCK_NUM;
}` верно?

Comment: это список инициализации. На начальном этапе понимания, можете считать, что внутри тела конструктора просто написано `_sock = MAX_SOCK_NUM;`

Comment: тогда во втором случае _sock = sock; ?

Comment: да, так оно и есть

Comment: а можно на пальцах про списки инициализации или куда пойти, но лучше на пальцах.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/58818/

Comment: тяжелый пример для функциональщика)) Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Такие перегруженные конструкторы — обычное дело. Другой вопрос в том, что часто это приводит к дублированию кода. Поэтому в данном случае можно было бы обойтись одним единственным с параметром по умолчанию:

```
EthernetClient(uint8_t sock = MAX_SOCK_NUM) : _sock(sock) { }
```

В более сложных случаях, начиная с c++11 можно выполнять делегирование конструкторов (вызов одного из другого):

```
EthernetClient() : EthernetClient(MAX_SOCK_NUM) { }
```

Делегирование позволяет избежать необходимости выноса общего кода в некую *init*-функцию.

Подробнее про инициализатор конструктора можно почитать тут: [Двоеточие в определении конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468496/176217)

Comment: EthernetClient(uint8_t sock = MAX_SOCK_NUM) : _sock(sock) { } такая конструкция точно будет принимать входной параметр?

Comment: не работает при вызове без параметров

Comment: @DowJhob будет принимать и должно работать. Если что-то не так, дайте ссылку на код, как пробуете. Список онлайн-компиляторов есть в описании метки [tag:c++]. Единственный момент — параметр по умолчанию следует задавать в заголовочном файле, но не в файле реализации.

Comment: размер бинарника не меняется, но такой способ пожалуй нагляднее