# Порядок инициализации параметров класса

Tags: c++, c++14

Добрый день.
Есть условный класс

```
class Class1
{
public:
   Class1()
      : m_foo(5)
   {
   }
   ~Class1();

   int m_foo = 3;
};
```

В случае создания объекта `Class1 my_class1;` сколько раз будет проинициализирована `m_foo`?

Comment: Почти  всегда лучше инициализировать только в конструкторе

Comment: @ARHovsepyan чем лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример из стандарта языка п. 12.6.2/9 (кстати, вопрос относится к c++11 и в c++14 изменений не претерпел):

> If a given non-static data member has both a *brace-or-equal-initializer* and a *mem-initializer*, the initialization specified by the *mem-initializer* is performed, and the non-static data member’s *brace-or-equal-initializer*
>   is ignored. [ Example: Given
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   int i = /∗ some integer expression with side effects ∗/ ;
>   A(int arg) : i(arg) { }
>   // ...
> };
> ```
>
> the `A(int)` constructor will simply initialize `i` to the value of `arg`, and the side effects in `i`’s *brace-or-equal-initializer* will not take place. —end example]

Переводя на русский: Если не статический член-данных имеет как инициализатор непосредственно в определении класса (через `=` или `{}`), т.е. *brace-or-equal-initializer*, так и инициализатор члена в [инициализаторе конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468507/176217), т.е. *mem-initializer*, то будет выполняться только инициализация в конструкторе. Инициализация непосредственно в классе будет проигнорирована. Это правило распространяется и на делегирование конструкторов (косвенная инициализация).

Дополнительно хочу заметить, что *инициализация* по определению может быть произведена не более одного раза, изменение значения переменной в дальнейшем - это уже присваивание.

Comment: Да, вы правы по терминологии и спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Один раз, значением 5. Значение 3 - на случай конструктора, в котором вы *не* инициализируете `m_foo`.

Comment: Т.е. для каждого из конструкторов будет создан код, который выберет значение либо из объявления (int m_foo = 3;), либо из конструктора (m_foo(5))?