# Язык C++. При определении конструктора класса через builder компилятор выдаёт предупреждения

Tags: c++, ооп

Создал класс через Builder.

Из-за чего компилятор выдаёт предупреждения в файле Patient.cpp на определении двух конструкторов класса и как это пофиксить?

Выдаёт два таких предупреждения:

> Warning   C26495  Variable 'Patient::id' is uninitialized. Always
> initialize a member variable (type.6).

Код файла Patient.h:

```
    #pragma once
    #include <string>
    class Patient
    {
    public:
        Patient();
        Patient(int id,std::string surname, std::string name, std::string patronymic, std::string address, std::string work_place, std::string last_date);
        ~Patient();
    protected:
        int id;//номер медицинской карты
        std::string surname;//фамилия
        std::string name;//имя
        std::string patronymic;//отчество
        std::string address;//адрес
        std::string work_place;//место работы
        std::string last_date;//дата последней флюрографии ???
    };
```

Код файла Patient.cpp:

```
    #include "Patient.h"
    #include <iostream>
    Patient::Patient()
    {
        std::cout << "Объект класса Patient создан\n";
    }
    
    Patient::Patient(int id, std::string surname, std::string name, std::string patronymic, std::string address, std::string work_place, std::string last_date)
    {
    this->id = id;
    this->surname= surname;//фамилия
    this->surname= name;//имя
    this->patronymic= patronymic;//отчество
    this->address= address;//адрес
    this->work_place= work_place;//место работы
    this->last_date= last_date;//дата последней флюрографии ???
    std::cout << "Объект класса Patient с использованием формальныъх параметров создан.\n";
        std::cout << "Объект класса Patient с использованием формальныъх параметров создан.\n";
    }


Patient::~Patient()
{
    std::cout << "Объект класса Patient удалён.\n";
}
```

Новая ошибка:

> Error C2274   '->': illegal as right side of '.' operator Lab10

При попытке заменить -> на точку поддчеркивает this и выдаёт:

> expression must have class type

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где вы инициализируете или используете эти поля класса?

Comment: конструктор должен инциализировать ВСЕ поля, иначе нет инварианта, обьект какраз не будет создан, как бы вы не пытались вывести на экран, что обьект создан

Comment: @pavel Вроде добавил инициализацию, но предупрждения остались, также появилась ошибка. Обновил пост.

Comment: "добавил инициализацию, но предупрждения остались" - вы выдумываете. И что значит "новая ошибка"? Где код, в котором возникла эта "ошибка"? Откуда мы должны знать, что вы там еще понаписывали?

Comment: Новая ошибка там, где используется this, то есть в Patient.cpp

Comment: Нет такой ошибки в том `Patient.cpp`, который вы здесь привели.

Comment: вообще не С++ стиль так писать через `this->` есть же форма через `Patient::Patient(.......):id(id)`

Comment: @AnT приложил скриншот

Comment: На вашем скриншоте не видно правой части кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конструкторе `Patient::Patient()` у вас поля инициализируются конструктором по-умолчанию, так что поле `int id;` с тривиальным конструктором остается неинициализированным (то бишь заполнено мусором). Соответственно его необходимо инициализировать:

```
Patient::Patient(): m_id{}
{
    std::cout << "Объект класса Patient создан\n";
}
```

Далее, в другом конструкторе все поля точно так же инициализируются конструктором по-умолчанию и только затем им присваиваются новые значения. Правильная инициализация выглядит так:

```
Patient::Patient(int id, std::string surname, std::string name, std::string patronymic, std::string address, std::string work_place, std::string last_date)
:   m_id{id}
,   m_surname{surname}
...
```

Ну и конечно имеет смысл использовать для полей такие имена, которые не приводят к конфликтам.

Comment: то есть "m_" нужно для различия между тем, что прописано в параметрах конструктора и полями самого класса?

Comment: @iwannaknow Ну да. префикс `m_` мне представляется самым распространённым вариантом.

Comment: А почему для пустого конструктора Patient::Patient() достаточно проинициализоровать только одну переменную для устранения предупреждения?

Comment: @iwannaknow Потому что у полей - экземпляров класса `std::string` конструктор по-умолчанию не тривиальный и инициализирует эти поля.

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор ожидает от вас именно *инициализации* поля `id` в конструкторе по умолчанию. Сгенерировать такую инициализацию вы можете либо явно написав [список инициализации конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468496/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0), либо неявно - указав инициализатор для `id` в теле класса

```
class Patient
{
  ...
protected:
  int id = 0;
  ...
};
```