# Что значит "запись" между именем конструктора и его телом в c++?

Tags: c++

Что значит "запись" между именем конструктора и его телом

```
Class a{
public:
int b,c;
а() :b(0)c(0) {тело}
}
```

Та и в принципе,до имя Функции пишется ее определение тип,и принадлежность к полям,
В теле пишется то что она делает,а что пишется между?
Для чего это пространство?

Comment: это список инициализации полей https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: Спасибо,это поле нужно для инициализации переменных класса,через конструктор, верно?

Comment: Поля класса - это b и с, переменных в классе нет. И да, список инициализации как раз служит для инициализации. Внутри тела конструктора инициализация полей уже завершена.

Comment: Все предельно ясно,но ,вы сказали что переменних в классе нет? То есть все те перемение которие я объявляю а классе, появляються лишь тогда когда я создаю объект этого класса?

Comment: Это не переменные, это поля класса. Переменные бывают в глобальной области видимости и в функциях. У переменных есть storage duration.

Comment: Это переменные-члены. А полей, как и методов в с++ пока не завозили.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Двоеточие в определении конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468496/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конструктор - функция, которая вызывается автоматически при создании объекта.

```
a(int value): b(value), c(0) { }
```

Это список инициализации. Эта конструкция
для создания членов с заданным значением. Это можно было бы сделать в самом, непосредственно, теле, но так эффективней, потому что вызывается только конструктор, и не вызывается оператор присваивания  Поэтому
константные и ссылочные члены можно  инициализировать в списке инициализации, но никак в теле конструктора Заметьте, что порядок инициализации переменных происходит в том порядке, в каком они объявлены в классе

Comment: Большое спасибо,то есть ,грубо говоря,это поле нужно для инициализации?

Comment: да, для этого оно и предназначено. кстати, можно поставить галочку)

Comment: Прошу прощения ,а как? Я просто только не давно узнал об этом сайте

Comment: возле ответа есть галочка

Comment: Хочу добавить, что если поля `b` и `c` являются экземплярами классов, то инициализировать их можно только через список инициализации. В теле конструктора это сделать не получится, т.к. нет способа непосредственно вызвать конструкторы для `b` и `c`.

Comment: **Эта конструкция    присваивает значения, указанные в скобках, переменным** ?  Вся прелесть в том, что как раз нет никакого присваивания. Присвоить можно в теле конструктора, а список инициализации  для конструирования объектов  с данными значениями(вызывается только конструктор).

Comment: Исправил ошибку

Comment: поправки ввел, ввиду их важности